# postman setNextRequest not executing

Tags: javascript, postman

I have this postman logic:

```
var returnData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
tests["status code"] = (responseCode.code === 401);
if (responseCode.code === 401) {
    postman.setNextRequest("get token with good login");
}
```

Even though status code is 401, that "setNextRequest" never get executed.
I am new to postman so maybe I am making a mistake somewhere?

Appreciate any pointer as to how I can chain this test and have it go onto to the next one?

thanks

-vincent

Comment: Is the API working if you use POSTMAN plugin?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I am using Chrome app version.   Is that the plugin that you are referring to?

Answer (score 22):

I figured out what's wrong.  I need to run the sequences in "Runner".  I was merely pressing "Send" beforehand.
Thanks for your reply.